# How to get last ListView item position

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I created a listview with radiobutton. The listview is like the image below: 
[image]

And my getView is:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    PaymentData rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                com.android.paypal.homeactivity.R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.radioBtn = (RadioButton) convertView
                .findViewById(com.android.paypal.homeactivity.R.id.rdb_payment_method);
        holder.btPaymentMethod = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(com.android.paypal.homeactivity.R.id.bt_item_event);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((position != mSelectedPosition) && (mSelectedRB != null)) {
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            mSelectedPosition = position;
            mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
        }
    });

    if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
        holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        if (mSelectedRB != null && holder.radioBtn != mSelectedRB) {
            mSelectedRB = holder.radioBtn;
        }
    }

    holder.radioBtn.setText(rowItem.getRdbText());
    holder.btPaymentMethod.setText(rowItem.getBtText());
    return convertView;

}
```

I want to auto checked the last radiobutton when the screen comes first. How can I achieve this.

Comment: you mean last radio button in the list?

Comment: yep. Please help me, I want this asap.

Comment: Last position is different from last visible position, clarify this..last position or lastVisible position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold a boolean to say whether user has himself selected anything. Let the boolean be `userSelected = false;`

Now you could do in `getView()`:

```
if(position==getCount()-1 && userSelected==false)
    holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
else
    holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
```

In onItemClick, when the user has made a selection himself, just set `userSelected=true;`

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thank you Aswin Kumar.

Comment: it's Correct Answer

Answer (score 6):

Your last position is , `int lastpostion = getcount() -1;` where `getcount()` is a method in the adpater class

Comment: At first I want to check the last position. Is this is last position then I want radion button setChecked(true).

Answer (score 0):

Using this method

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == onScroll) {
                if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                    //Update new data here
                                            // and then, notify your adapter 
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }

    });
```